# read json JsonResponse django

Tags: html, django

I'm trying to read data Json Data sent from Django views in html.

The query depends on the on the url. I query data depending in the ikey. I dont't know how to read the data especially in the data-url="{% url 'show_pp'| add:selection pk=ikey %}.
If i have a static data-url it works, but i don't know how to create a dynamic url depending on the ikey.

Thank you very much for your help. I'm really stuck here.

Here is the code:

Django urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('show_pp/<str:ikey>/', views.show_pp, name = 'show_pp'),
path('plant', views.plant, name = 'plant'),
]
```

Django views:

```
def show_pp(request, ikey, *args, **kwargs):
"code..."
queryset = CriMvProductionPlan.objects.filter(plant=str(ikey))
"code..."
  data = {
    'ikey': ikey,
    'month': date_list,
    'generation': generation_list,
    'quantity': quantity_list,
  }

return JsonResponse(data)
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 75%;">
<canvas id="data_pp" data-url="{% url 'show_pp'| add:selection pk=ikey %}"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending what your app name is, i will suppose for the case of the example, that it is
"app_name":

I believe that the url should be

```
data-url="{% url 'app_name:show_pp' ikey=ikey %}">
```

The problem that you get, is that in your url, and view you never use 'pk' as a name of a variable, it is always a string named 'ikey', so it is what you need to pass through the url.

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer.
I made a few changes and the syntax I was looking for was:
<canvas id="data_pp" data-url="{% url 'data_pp' ikey  %}"></canvas>